# Map an array with parent Owner property to and Array with children property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am trying to map an array which is as below:

```
var currentModel = [{id: 'Iron Man (CPC Avengers)', label: 'Iron Man', unit: 'CPC Avengers', level: '2', parent: '', children: []}, {id: 'Thor (Avengers Core Asgard)', label: 'Thor', unit: 'Avengers Core Asgard', level: '3', parent: 'Iron Man', children: []}, {id: 'Loki (Avengers Asgard)', label: 'Loki', unit: 'Avengers Asgard', level: '4', parent: 'Thor', children: []}, {id: 'Hela (Avengers Asgard)', label: 'Hela', unit: 'Avengers Asgard', level: '4', parent: 'Thor', children: []}, {id: 'Groot (Guardians of Galaxy)', label: 'Groot', unit: 'Guardians of Galaxy', 'level: '5', parent: 'Loki', children: []}, {id: 'Captain America (Avengers Core Earth)', label: 'Captain America', unit: 'Avengers Core Earth', level: '3', parent: 'Iron Man', children: []}, {id: 'Black Widow (Avengers Earth)', label: 'Black Widow', unit: 'Avengers Earth', level: '4', parent: 'Captain America', children: []}, {id: 'Hulk (Avengers Earth)', label: 'Hulk', unit: 'Avengers Earth', level: '4', parent: 'Captain America', children: []}]
```

Into Below Array

```
var requiredModel = [ {id: 'Iron Man (CPC Avengers)', label: 'Iron Man', unit: 'CPC Avengers', level: '2', parent: '', children: [ { id: 'Thor (Avengers Core Asgard)', label: 'Thor', unit: 'Avengers Core Asgard', level: '3', parent: 'Iron Man', children: [ { id: 'Loki (Avengers Asgard)', label: 'Loki', unit: 'Avengers Asgard', level: '4', parent: 'Thor', children: [ { id: 'Groot (Guardians of Galaxy)', label: 'Groot', unit: 'Guardians of Galaxy', level: '5', parent: 'Loki', children: []} ]}, {id: 'Hela (Avengers Asgard)', label: 'Hela', unit: 'Avengers Asgard', level: '4', parent: 'Thor', children: []}]},{id: 'Captain America (Avengers Core Earth)', label: 'Captain America', unit: 'Avengers Core Earth', level: '3', parent: 'Iron Man', children: [{ id: 'Black Widow (Avengers Earth)', label: 'Black Widow', unit: 'Avengers Earth', level: '4', parent: 'Captain America', children:[]}, { id: 'Hulk (Avengers Earth)', label: 'Hulk', unit: 'Avengers Earth', level: '4', children: []}]}]}]
```

I tried following things on currentModel:

Step1: To have separate array with respective levels

`var currentModelLvl2= currentModel.filter(function(item){ return item.level === '2'});
var currentModelLvl3= currentModel.filter(function(item){ return item.level === '3'});
var currentModelLvl4= currentModel.filter(function(item){ return item.level === '4'});
var currentModelLvl5= currentModel.filter(function(item){ return item.level === '5'});`

Step2: Loop over currentModelLvl4 and currentModelLvl5 and add to the children array of currentModelLvl4 the items from currentModelLvl5 where currentModelLvl4.label === currentModelLvl5.parent

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentModelLvl4.length; i++) {
var currentModelItem4 = currentModelLvl4[i];
for (var j = 0; j < currentModelLvl5.length; j++) {
    var currentModelItem5 = currentModelLvl4[j];
    if (currentModelItem4.label === currentModelItem5.parent) {
        currentModelItem4.children.push( currentModelItem5);
    }
}}
```

But my loop gets stuck and makes my browser crash is anything wrong with my method or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: it was a typo made the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentModel = [{id: 'Iron Man (CPC Avengers)', label: 'Iron Man', unit: 'CPC Avengers', level: '2', parent: '', children: []}, {id: 'Thor (Avengers Core Asgard)', label: 'Thor', unit: 'Avengers Core Asgard', level: '3', parent: 'Iron Man', children: []}, {id: 'Loki (Avengers Asgard)', label: 'Loki', unit: 'Avengers Asgard', level: '4', parent: 'Thor', children: []}, {id: 'Hela (Avengers Asgard)', label: 'Hela', unit: 'Avengers Asgard', level: '4', parent: 'Thor', children: []}, {id: 'Groot (Guardians of Galaxy)', label: 'Groot', unit: 'Guardians of Galaxy', level: '5', parent: 'Loki', children: []}, {id: 'Captain America (Avengers Core Earth)', label: 'Captain America', unit: 'Avengers Core Earth', level: '3', parent: 'Iron Man', children: []}, {id: 'Black Widow (Avengers Earth)', label: 'Black Widow', unit: 'Avengers Earth', level: '4', parent: 'Captain America', children: []}, {id: 'Hulk (Avengers Earth)', label: 'Hulk', unit: 'Avengers Earth', level: '4', parent: 'Captain America', children: []}];

var children = {};
currentModel.forEach(model => {
  children[model.parent] = children[model.parent] || [];
  children[model.parent].push(model);
  children[model.label] = model.children = children[model.label] || model.children;
});

console.log(children[""]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this should do it
var values = [{
    "id": "uniqueParentId1",
    "children": [{
      "childProp1": "test1",
      "childProp2": "test3"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "uniqueParentId2",
    "children": [{
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
      },
      {
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var result = values.map(value =>
  value.children.map(child => Object.assign({ parentId: value.id }, child))
).reduce((l, n) => l.concat(n), []);

console.log(result);
```